# EC2 Instance do not have public IP address

Tags: amazon-ec2

After I create a instance in the ec2 cloud, I only see the private IP/DNS and public DNS but no public IP address. Is there a way to activate a public IP address in the console? (not the elastic ip address).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public IP is part of the public DNS record, ie:

ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Here, the X's would be the IP address you're looking for.